# Magento ajax grid. Save choices between grid pages

Tags: ajax, magento, grid

I'm using adminhtml grid in my module in tab loaded via ajax. [image: grid]

The problem is it won't save choices I made on another grid pages. For example if I choose 2 products on the first page of the grid, then load second page of the grid and choose another 3 products and then load 1st page - All choices I made on this page of the grid is lost.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a grid serializer for your grid.
What this serialized does is to add a hidden input below the products grid and each time you check/uncheck a checkbox the id of the product is added to that hidden input or removed from it.

[Here is a tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/13309/146) about how you can add product grid with selection to your custom entity. It seams you already implemented a part of it.
To see what else you need to do check the section that starts with "Now the layout for these 2 actions". That will show you how to add the grid serializer and the section that starts with "Now saving the data." to see how you can save the data in the db.